# How to save report results from console to a file (TestCafe)?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, end-to-end

I'm doing e2e tests with Test-cafe. I would like to know if there is a way to save the report results from the console to a file. So, every time the tests are finished, the results are automatically saved in a separate file that I could use to see what's wrong, etc.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/

ps. I'm using Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [reporter option](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-r-nameoutput---reporter-nameoutput) (`-r`, `--reporter`) to output to a file.

For example, `testcafe chrome example.js -r spec:output.txt` produces the following file:

[image]

You can find the [list of built in reporters here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/reporters.html), as well as some links to custom reporters that you would have to install separately.

Comment: Is there a way to show the information provided in the metadata under fixture? https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#using-metadata-in-reports

Comment: @luka98v Not with the built-in reporters it seems. You'd have to find a reporter that included it (such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-json-complete) or customize one yourself