# Testcafe: find current working directory from test

Tags: testcafe

I have a working TestCafe test suite which generates a custom xml report generated by code in the test suite. I would like to place this report in the "standard" `./results` location that TestCafe uses for its reports, but I can't find an option to retrieve the current working directory (e.g., the bash `pwd` command).

I'm getting it by adding `export pwd=$(pwd)` on the command line when I run the test, but I wonder if there's a built-in mechanism in TestCafe to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you run the tests from the command line, you can just use the `reporter` option as follows:

`testcafe chrome test.js --reporter xunit:results/output.txt`

See this question for details: [How to save report results from console to a file (TestCafe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169471/how-to-save-report-results-from-console-to-a-file-testcafe).

Comment: Sorry, @Alex Kamaev... I wasn't clear in my question. I'm writing my own report, not using any of the "standard" report writers so that won't work. I use the `--reporter` option in most of my other reports. I'll just keep using my exported approach.